# Convert string date to date value

Tags: string, excel, date, formula

I extracted table from MySQL then when I copy it to excel I wasn't able to convert the field of "date".

Sample date with day and time:

```
Tuesday 7th October 2014, 4:8 PM
```

How can i convert it using excel formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your date string is in cell A1:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99),",",""),"th",""),"st",""),"nd",""),"rd",""))
```

Then apply date number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the time you could use

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,99))
```

then apply time formatting.

If you add this to the previous answer you will get a datetime value.